# A less extreme version of paranoia

Tags: word-choice, word-request

What are some words which can describe the feeling that everyone just dislikes you and doesn't want to talk to you. I think that it would be something similar to paranoia but a less extreme version of it. Although I am not really sure about it.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks

Comment: Opinions may differ, but I'd say ***delusional, alienated,*** and ***neurotic*** are somewhat less extreme. But they cover a broader range of "inappropriate" feelings (about more than just how one perceives the intentions of others). For something *much* less extreme, how about ***distrustful, suspicious**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I want to convey the feeling of loneliness. Probably something like opposite of solitude.

Comment: @user185887 Antisocial?

Comment: @AngelPray Nope. Antisocial means that I dislike people. I want to convey that I feel that everyone dislikes me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind would be indeed obsession/ paranoia, but it's too broad of a term.

The second one would be the **critical inner voice** that keeps reminding us that we aren’t good enough and don’t deserve love etc. And the other terms in this category like **critical-** or **negative-self image** and **negative self-talk**.

---

Also, this negative attitude makes me think of a number of emotions and feelings like that 
***I'm not good enough to be liked; I'm boring/ ugly/ stupid; no one wants to listen to me; no one cares about me; I have no one; I’m alone*** and these *insecurities* might be expressed by these words:

I'm not good enough: **insecurity < low self-esteem < inferiority complex < self-hatred**

I'm alone: **distant < seclusion < loneliness < social isolation** (the most extreme)

As you can see this is quite a list and at some point meanings of these words may slightly overlap, so see for yourself if any of these words 'hits you' as the one you were looking for.